# Problems with reading data from QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, sockets, qt4, client

I've modified the [threaded fortune-server](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/network-threadedfortuneserver.html) from Qt examples.
The client connects to the server and then sends a header to authenticate.

```
tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket();
tcpSocket->connectToHost(addr, port);
QByteArray block = "someheader";
int x = tcpSocket->write(block);
qDebug() << x;
```

The client seems OK here and `qDebug` prints the actual size of `block`.

On the server side I've predefined `incomingConnection` and I start thread to each new connection.

```
void Server::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor) {
    const QString &str = vec[qrand() % vec.size()];
    SpellThread *thread = new SpellThread(socketDescriptor, str);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    qDebug() << " -- incoming connection";
    thread->start();
}
```

I'm connecting `sock` to check is there something to read. (`sock` here is `QTcpServer*`)

```
void SpellThread::run() {
    qDebug() << " -- in spellthread";
    connect(sock, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(checkBytes()));
    //....
    qDebug() << " -- end spellthread";
}
```

The first problem is that when I'm sending data from the client, `readyRead` is not fired. (I've added debug message in `checkBytes`)
Messages are:

```
 -- incoming connection 
 -- in spellthread 
 -- end spellthread
```

Although the client prints the actual size of header length.

The second problem is that `checkBytes` currently is very bad-designed. First it checks is header OK and sets a flag, then it gets the size of message and sets another flag and finally it gets the real message. This is very clumsy. I first tried to escape signals and instead use `sock->waitForReadyRead()`. However it always returns false. (From the docs: "Reimplement this function to provide a blocking API for a custom device. The default implementation does nothing, and returns false.").

So how to really make a client/server application in Qt with multiple clients and multiple reads/writes? I really want suggestions to improve design of my application and to solve my current two problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use slots or socket signals with a thread without calling `QThread::exec()` to start an event loop within that thread/the run function.

Since your `checkBytes` slot belongs to QThread, it wouldn't be executed by the thread (there is a detailed article about QThreads [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects#64a093776750c691afdeb133a80f55e2))

The closest example that seems to already do what you want is the [Network Chat](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/network-network-chat.html) (particularly the two classes `Server` and `Connection`).

----------
**Edit** 

If you need to use threads (without any slot), the `QTcpSocket` object must belongs to the same thread as the one where you call `waitForReadyRead`. For example, with:

```
SpellThread::SpellThread(int socketDescriptor, const QString & str) {
    tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket(); // There should be no parent to be able
                                  // to move it to the thread
    tcpSocket->moveToThread(this);
    ...
```

Or by creating the `QTcpSocket` object inside the `run` function so that it automatically belongs to that thread (it was briefly explained in the fortune example).
If you allocate the QTcpSocket dynamically, and because it won't have a parent, you should also delete it manually.

Comment: I need threads because there are a lot of computations involved when a client connects. I don't want to use signals at all -- just want to read some data from a new client and then send back some data; eventually if the client doesn't send data, to time out. However `waitForReadyRead` doesn't do the trick and always fails. Can you give me some suggestions without signals?

Comment: I tried the version without signals and I had a problem with this line of code: `while ( sock.bytesAvailable() < 4 );`. I expected that the socket will know when bytes came. I changed it to this: `while ( sock.bytesAvailable() < 4 ) sock.waitForReadyRead();` and now I don't have any problems. Thanks for your answer, I accept it. :)